# Spark driver parsing transformation is taking long time, why?

Tags: apache-spark

We have spark application which reads json file with complex types arrays and structs.

We have written a transformations to flatten the structure out and save in hdfs.

Job completes in same amount of time (around 24 minutes) for 10 gb to 100gb of data. (Runs in dynamic allocation)

However strange thing we observed is driver program parsing transformations is taking more time (15 mins) than actual conversion of data. Also during this time no executor is used. We have displayed print statement after each transformation to determine the time.

What could be the reason for consumption this large amount of time to just parse the transformations? I assumed driver parses statements in secs, but that is not the case.

Below is the log details, from 3:55:02 to 04:12:08 there is action present in driver. Only action is trigger at 04:12:08 using persist and then followed by save at 04:19:11

```
18/08/25 03:55:02 INFO Processor: Read JSON files
18/08/25 03:55:02 INFO Processor: Started splitting reservation by stay day
18/08/25 03:55:02 INFO Processor: Structuring BSeg
18/08/25 03:55:09 INFO Processor: Structuring oldSeg
18/08/25 03:55:15 INFO Processor: Structuring BN
18/08/25 03:55:20 INFO Processor: Structuring Name
18/08/25 03:55:23 INFO Processor: Structuring address
18/08/25 03:55:31 INFO Processor: Structuring Email
18/08/25 03:55:37 INFO Processor: Structuring Phone
18/08/25 03:55:48 INFO Processor: Structuring ptSeg
18/08/25 03:56:08 INFO Processor: Structuring TEST
18/08/25 03:56:51 INFO Processor: Structuring BN
18/08/25 03:58:07 INFO Processor: Adding tranaction type boolean
18/08/25 03:58:35 INFO Processor: updating status
18/08/25 03:58:47 INFO Processor: adding segment cancels
18/08/25 04:00:00 INFO Processor: los rule applied
18/08/25 04:00:13 INFO Processor: Geting date
18/08/25 04:00:30 INFO Processor: Getting Rate
18/08/25 04:00:43 INFO Processor: Exploding  BSeg/OLDSeg to multiple rows
18/08/25 04:00:55 INFO Processor: getting seg info
18/08/25 04:01:16 INFO Processor: Selecting required columns
18/08/25 04:01:24 INFO Processor: Applying UDFs
18/08/25 04:02:35 INFO Processor: calling get portal df
18/08/25 04:03:00 INFO Processor: Started Vector directory Name
18/08/25 04:03:12 INFO Processor: Step 3: Completed. GNR record exploded to 1 record/day
18/08/25 04:03:12 INFO Processor: join to Dimensions started
18/08/25 04:04:39 INFO Processor: Join to Dimension Completed 
18/08/25 04:06:28 INFO Processor: Join to Dimension Completed 
18/08/25 04:08:33 INFO Processor: Step 4: Completed. Joined to dimensions
18/08/25 04:12:08 INFO Processor: Checking for empty dataframe  -- persist method called
18/08/25 04:19:11 INFO Processor: Persist Data is true. Target Hive Table 
18/08/25 04:20:40 INFO Processor: Step 5: Completed. Saved to hive table
```

Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: How can you write  `transformations` & run on driver only? It's non sense

Answer (score 0):

How can you write transformations & run on driver only? It's non-sense.

Your spark's transformations & actions will be run on workers.

Anyway, you should provide the code. Without the code we cant say anything